# How to visit a link inside an email using capybara

Tags: ruby, testing, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I am new to cucumber with capybara. I got an application to test whose flow is:'after submitting a form, an email will be sent to the user which contains the link to another app. In order to access the app we have to open the mail and click the link, which will redirect to the app.'. I don't have access to the mail Id. Is there any way to extract that link and continue with the flow?
Please, give some possible way to do it.

Regards,
Abhisek Das

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your test, use whatever means you need in order to trigger the sending of the email by your application. Once the email is sent, use a regular expression to find the URL from the link within the email body (note this will work only for an email that contains a single link), and then visit the path from that URL with Capybara to continue with your test:

```
path_regex = /(?:"https?\:\/\/.*?)(\/.*?)(?:")/    

email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
path = email.body.match(path_regex)[1]
visit(path)
```

**Regular expression explained**

A regular expression (regex) itself is demarcated by forward slashes, and this regex in particular consists of three *groups*, each demarcated by pairs of parentheses. The first and third groups both begin with `?:`, indicating that they are *non-capturing* groups, while the second is a *capturing* group (no `?:`). I will explain the significance of this distinction below.

The first group, `(?:"https?\:\/\/.*?)`, is a:

- non-capturing group, `?:`
- that matches a single double quote, `"`

  - we match a quote since we anticipate the URL to be in the `href="..."` attribute of a link tag
- followed by the string `http`
- optionally followed by a lowercase *s*, `s?`

  - the question mark makes the preceding match, in this case `s`, optional
- followed by a colon and two forward slashes, `\:\/\/`

  - note the backslashes, which are used to *escape* characters that otherwise have a special meaning in a regex
- followed by a wildcard, `.*?`, which will match any character any number of times up until the next match in the regex is reached

  - the period, or wildcard, matches any character
  - the asterisk, `*`, repeats the preceding match up to an unlimited number of times, depending on the successive match that follows
  - the question mark makes this a *lazy* match, meaning the wildcard will match as few characters as possible while still allowing the next match in the regex to be satisfied

The second group, `(\/.*?)` is a capturing group that:

- matches a single forward slash, `\/`

  - this will match the first forward slash after the host portion of the URL (e.g. the slash at the end of `http://www.example.com/`) since the slashes in `http://` were already matched by the first group
- followed by another lazy wildcard, `.*?`

The third group, `(?:")`, is:

- another non-capturing group, `?:`
- that matches a single double quote, `"`

And thus, our second group will match the portion of the URL starting with the forward slash after the host and going up to, but not including, the double quote at the end of our `href="..."`.

When we call the `match` method using our regex, it returns an instance of `MatchData`, which behaves much like an array. The element at index `0` is a string containing the entire matched string (from all of the groups in the regex), while elements at subsequent indices contain only the portions of the string matched by the regex's capturing groups (only our second group, in this case). Thus, to get the corresponding match of our second group—which is the path we want to visit using Capybara—we grab the element at index `1`.

Comment: Actually when the form is filled and submitted, a request is sent to server which send a link to the respective user though email.

Comment: do i need to add some specific gem for this? Its showing 'unknown error:'URL' must be a string' error.

Comment: It sounds like the `match` method isn't returning the correct path. Can you please revise your question to include the body of the email (`email.body` in my code snippet, above)?

Comment: thanks, brian...i uploaded a new question..simultaneously looking for the solution as well.

Comment: I re verified the code..Its showing 'Undefined method 'body' for "":string at step 'path = email.body.match(path_regex)[1]' and 'unknown error:'URL' must be a string' error for step "visit(path)"..

Comment: Okay @Abhisek, it looks like our `email` variable just holds a string instead of an email. Can you take a look at this: http://stevelorek.com/actionmailer-cucumber.html

Comment: hi brian...Tried the steps as per the link u sent but still the same error message. Can u tell me what configuration u did?

Comment: @Abhisek, I'm not using Cucumber, so I'm not sure if my configuration would be the same as yours. If I'm not mistaken, however, I don't think I changed any of the defaults for `ActionMailer` in my test suite. Could you try this line: `expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries).not_to be_empty` right after the line that defines `path_regex`?

Comment: Hi brian...Still the same error :( .. is there any other way to do it?abhisekearly@gmail.com is my emailId, you can contact me there...

Answer (score 7):

You can use Nokogiri to parse the email body and find the link you want to click.

Imagine you want to click a link *Change my password*:

```
email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
html = Nokogiri::HTML(email.html_part.body.to_s)
target_url = html.at("a:contains('Change my password')")['href']
visit target_url
```

I think this is more semantic and robust that using regular expressions. For example, this would work if the email has many links.

Comment: Use `email.html_part.body` to get only the html part of the body. If you have text type body, `email.body`will fail.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using or willing to use the [capybara-email gem](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/capybara-email), there's now a simpler way of doing this. Let's say you've generated an email to `recipient@email.com`, which contains the link '[fancy link](https://example.com)'.

Then you can just do this in your test suite:

```
open_email('recipient@email.com') # Allows the current_email method
current_email.click_link 'fancy link'
```